# Input widget in QApplication in a dedicated thread causes QTimer to be stopped from the wrong thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, timer

For different reasons I have to create a `QApplication` that does not live in the main thread of my program. This works well except for the cleanup part. Once `main()` finishes I get the following notification:

> `QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread`

This happens quite some time after all Qt widgets and windows as well as the `QApplication` have been disposed of.

I narrowed the problem down to this minimal example:

```
#include <thread>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QLineEdit>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::thread t { 
        [&] {
            QApplication app{argc, argv};

            QLineEdit w{"Test"};
            w.showNormal();

            app.exec();
        }
    };

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{3});

    QApplication::instance()->quit();

    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

A `QSpinBox` instead of a `QLineEdit` leads to the same behavior. When I use a `QLabel` however, no warning is issued. So I suspect that the culprit is a timer responsible for cursor flashing but I might be wrong here.

Is there any way to stop this (invisible) timer correctly when quitting the `QApplication`?

Comment: I would try calling `QApplication::exit` instead of directly call the `quit` slot

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o according to the docs calling `QApplication::quit()` is equivalent to calling `QApplication::exit(0)`. It also does not affect the warning.

Comment: Apart from anything else you're accessing the `QApplication` instance from multiple threads.  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @G.M. I was not aware of that. Is there anything specific about this in the documentation? I would also be happy with manually posting something like a `QuitEvent` in the application's event loop instead of calling `quit()`directly.

Comment: The basic issue is that what you're trying to do -- initialize/use Qt on a thread other than that in  which `main` was invoked -- isn't generally supported.  Even if it appears to work in a certain situation your code will be very fragile.  Why do you think you need to do things this way?  As it stands this appears to be an XY question.

Comment: The main application is implemented against another (proprietary) framework which expects to run in the main thread and is concerned with OpenGL rendering. During development I want to change some parameters at runtime in a simple GUI. For Release builds this GUI should be easily removable. So basing everything on a QApplication is not feasible. However Qt was the simplest option to design and build the interface.

Comment: You should make your tuning application a second application and put the tuning parameters into something easy to use, e.g. global shared memory. Take a look at QSharedMemory

Comment: I understand the arguments and thank you for your input. But considering that I already implemented everything and it works without flaw as expected I think I will just tolerate one warning message on program shutdown. Once things are starting to break down I will consider your alternatives. ^^

Comment: You might experience crashes or deadlocks or malfunctions on sockets during the execution of such code, not only during shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

> I would also be happy with manually posting something like a QuitEvent
>   in the application's event loop instead of calling quit()directly.

Here you go:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QApplication::instance(), "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to access widgets and other related elements from anywhere but the main thread. This is common with nearly all GUI systems (e.g. MFC, BGI, ...).
For Qt there is a hint on this in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html). Surprisingly enough not even a QPixmap is allowed in worker threads.